# legends are gone in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a setting that kills legends in ggplot?

I dont get legends on my plots. I run the code below, and legends are missing? (this code should result in a plot with legends?)

```
XX <- seq(1:100)
YY <- runif(100,10,30)
Dat<- (seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("2009/1/1"), "years"))
df <- data.frame(XX,YY,Dat)

ggplot(data=df) +
geom_line(aes(x=Dat, y= XX), color= "Steelblue", size=1)+
geom_line(aes(x=Dat, y= YY), color= "Darkred", size = 1)
```

I have tried a lot of things, but nothing gives me a legendd that indicates that the steelblue line is the XX dataseries, and the YY is darkred

Comment: Can't reproduce, try starting a new R session.

Comment: Agree with @PoGibas; also, the multiple `data = bike_share_data` and `aes(group = 1)` statements are redundant in `geom_point` and `geom_line`.

Comment: When I use this code, on a different computer, there is no legends. There is something wrong with my fundamental syntax

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is that i used a code as a proxy and changed it in the wrong way. The correct syntax for the example above is:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes( x=Dat)) +
geom_line(aes( y= XX, colour="XX"), size=1)+
geom_line(aes( y= YY, colour="YY"), size = 1)+
scale_color_manual(values=c("Darkred", "Steelblue"))
```